# MS Access - split one text field dynamically into columns

Tags: ms-access, split, vba

I have an Excel file with 900+ column I need to import on regular basis into Access. Unfortunately I get the Excel file as such and can't change the data structure. The good news is I only need few columns of those 900+. Unfortunately MS Access can't work with files more than 255 columns.

So the idea is to import as csv file with all columns in each row in just text field. And then using VBA in Access via split to break it out again.

Question:
As I don't need all columns I want to only keep some items. So I have as input a list of column numbers I need to keep. The list is dynamic in a sense it is user defined. There is a table with all item numbers users wants to have.

I can relatively easy split the sourceTbl field.

```
SELECT split(field1, vbTab) from sourceTbl
```

If I would know I always need to extract certain columns I could probalby write in some

```
SELECT getItem(field1, vbTab, 1), getItem(field1, vbTab, 4), ...
```

Where getItem would be custom function to return item number i. Problem is which/how many columns to retrieve is not static. I read that dynamically from another table that lists the item numbers to keep.

Sample Data: 
sourceTbl: field1 = abc;def;rtz;jkl;wertz;hjk

columnsToKeep: 1,4,5

Should output: abc, jkl, wertz

Excel files have around 20k rows each. About 100 MB data per file. Talking about 5 files per import. Filtered on the needed columns all data imported is about 50 MB.

Comment: Why not avoid the import issue by running a function in Excel that will copy the desired columns to a new sheet, then you can import that sheet (and I'm guessing the column count will be less than 255 by then)?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing at the moment. But as I'm copying quite some data I was hoping to get better performance if I do the whole import within Access

Comment: What's the total size of the workbook (MB or KB)? How many rows? What's the average number of columns selected?